# Does anyone know the 'if, then' statement for the inscribed angle theorem?

Tags: geometry

I am just wondering what the if, then statement for the inscribed angle theorem is. I am seeking to prove its converse, but I can't get the initial statement right.

Comment: will you please ellaborate a bit?

Comment: the theorem where the angle subtended at the centre is twice the angle subtended at the circumference

Comment: Do you want the proof?

Comment: I would like the if and then statement for the theorem. However, a proof for the converse would be nice.

Comment: Well, it is not normally shown in "if-then" form. You may say "*if a point $A$ is on the circumference, then the angle subtended at $A$ is half of the angle subtended at centre*" and then you may want to prove the converse (sort of): "*if the angle subtended at $A$ is half of the angle subtended at centre, then $A$ lies on the circumference*".

Comment: Do you want to write an algorithm for it in any programming language?

Comment: (In fact, the way I formulated it, it is probably not true, but only just. If the angle subtended at $A$ is $\lt 90^\circ$, then additionally you need to require $A$ and the centre to be on the same side of the chord; if the angle subtended at $A$ is $\gt 90^\circ$, then $A$ and the centre must lie on the opposite sides of the chord. For the angle exactly $90^\circ$, $A$ can be on either side.)

Comment: @Stinking Bishop your statement is the one I'm looking for. thanks